# How to prevent JavaScript Injection Attacks

Tags: javascript

Currently I have developed a site which is used for handle financial transactions. I have seen that some of my customers have done JavaScript injection attacks and have done some transactions which are not possible. As a example I have checked his cash balance before he place the order. But some of them did change that by running the following javascript in the address bar. They have taken the varible name by looking in to page source.

```
javascript:void(document.accounts.cashBalence.value="10000000")
```

Since this is critical I want to fixed it quickly. So is there a way to prevent JavaScript injection attacks?

Comment: Please let me know which bank this is, so I can.... er, see? [cough]

Comment: Are you for real? Like you can actually manipulate an account balance via JS on a live financial site?? Dude. no way. I hope your joking.

Comment: Have you looked at Interpolique?   http://www.recursion.com/interpolique.html

Comment: I have strted to do the server side validations. It is still in testing stage. Thanks for all your suggestions

Comment: While all of the suggestions here were perfectly valid in 2010 javascript can now run on the server side as well, with NodeJS, and you can port your JS validation code to the server.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can obfuscate or hash variable names and/or values. However,
Don't use JavaScript, do every logic in the server-side instead.

Comment: +10k Who could possibly think that leaving critical business logic up to the client's computer without checks on the server is a good idea?

Comment: well for one, don't use javascript on banking sites. one less thing to worry about. no need for an "AJAX" experience.

Comment: It is fine to *use* javascript, but only for the UI logic and sanity checking **at the client**. The server should *trust nothing*.

Comment: @RPM Javascript on banking sites is fine, **as long as it's only used to enhance the interface.**

Comment: Agreed. Some simple DOM manipulation is fine. But i wouldn't be making AJAX calls.

Comment: @RPM Making AJAX calls is fine too, **as long as the server checks and double checks the validity of those.**

Comment: I shouldn't have said anything, should i. :)

Comment: @RPM Saying something is fine, **as long as you check the validity of what you're saying.** ;o)

Comment: Hahahaha, touche` my friend, touche`. +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 9):

In the end it's not even a problem of Javascript. Your server talks to the outside world using HTTP. It sends data using HTTP and receives data using HTTP. Anybody can request data from it using HTTP and anybody can send data to it using HTTP.

Think about this again:
**Anybody can send data to your server through the very simple protocol that is HTTP**.

The HTML and Javascript you're sending to people's browsers is just a nice help, *an interface*, to allow them to easily send data to your server. They could do the same using the `curl` command on their command line or by `telnet`'ing into port 80 and talk really low-level to it.

If your server blindly obeys any and all commands sent to it without checking their validity, you have ***no security*** whatsoever. Security and validity checks **belong on the server**, not on the client side interface. Because HTML and Javascript aren't the only interface to your server, nor are they in any way protectable and hence trustworthy.

Answer (score 7):

Javascript runs in the user's browser.  You ultimately have no control over it and should not trust it.  Any verification you do in the browser is merely for the user's convenience so they can be alerted of problems as early as possible.

The backend code that accepts the order should do the authoritative check of the user's balance.

Answer (score 1):

No client-side scripting (including Javascript) is good for verification, It should all be done on the server-side.

It is too unreliable to trust it specially if it is for financial records!!

It should be used for a better "user experience". Form validation while typing or whatever but not this!

Answer (score 0):

Have found that if you make it to where server only excepts out going data not incoming data it works best but that poses a problem, if you are using a website that takes user input on the connected client then your preaty much screwed I sugset a simple java script line that in a sence makes it to where before you can send any java script you have to enter a basic set of variables so in a sence just have a  login page start with somthing like this

```
System.out.printin ("Welcome, Would you like to login to edit?")
```

Then { System.in = "Yes"}

Answer (score -2):

To prevent Javascript injection, you should have a **Validation Feature** whenever you allow your user to enter something. Try to use libraries that determine Javascript scripts that are entered to the form.

Also when displaying user inputs, you should **Escape Texts** to display it as is and will not be evaluated by the browser.

Utilize your server, your should place your business logic to the server and not to the client whether using Javascript or not. All data sent to the client are just view and should not process any business logic.

Comment: He said people manipulated Javascript by entering snippets in the address bar (same as using the Javascript console), your tips won't help there.