# preventing javascript injections from navigation bar

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with cookies and stuff, until I noticed a website saying that you can easily set cookies via the navigation bar with one simple code;

`javascript: document.cookie="SESSID=IDOFSESSIONHERE;path=/"`

while doing this, I could login on one computer, copy the cookie data to another computer, and set the same cookie via this code, after a refresh I was logged in with the same user.

(just on a simple webpage I made myselve)

this seems like a security issue to me, I mean, ofcourse they would first need to get the cookie data, but without that, I imagine that you could do alot of damage with the `javascript:` from the cookies aside.

Is there any way to prevent the usage of `javascript:` from the navigation bar?

Comment: +1, legit concern. But what's to stop you from simply using their computer for your bidding in the first place?  No need to copy credentials over.  And, if not navbar, what about devtools? Even if there was a way to prevent this, it could still be circumvented. Best just to treat your computer like your wallet. ;-)

Comment: @JamesM.Lay Thanks for your comment, but This cookies thing was just an example, im more concerned about other malicious code which might get included, would that be possible this way?

Comment: @Azrael - As you have no control - none whatsoever - there is nothing you can do to prevent any code being run

Comment: Absolutely.  Any javascript, any element on page, including values of password forms, can be accessed in plaintext through the javascript console.  Nothing can be done there, unfortunately.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay That was what I wanted to hear, well ofcourse I need a solution for this.. but my thoughts are confirmed ;p

Comment: You should take a look at cookie encryption and httpOnly cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user is the security issue not Javascript. The user gave you the session id - i.e. do you give out your keys/passwords to others? If you do what can the site do? Send around a blioke to look over your sholder all the time

Comment: Though I know Javascript is Clientside, there is no way of like ehm.. including malicious scripts? (i'm pretty new with javascript)

Comment: Exactly what @Ed said.  The user is the security issue here. This is the type of vulnerability that social engineering capitalizes on.  You're not really exploiting the computer, you're exploiting the ignorance of its user.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent JavaScript usage from the navigation bar. I could visit your website and use the Internet Explorer debug tool, Chrome debug tool or FireBug to launch JavaScript code on your page.

Since JavaScript runs on the on the visitor's local computer, you will have no control over it. Only the visitor has control over what cookies will be stored in the browser.

What you need to do is to take measurements of security server-side. But yes, all authentication-processes that depend on a session cookie will have the security issue you are explaining.

Comment: I know javascript is clientside, but there really is no way this could be dangerous? (sorry im pretty new to javascript)

Comment: Well, as you yourself stated. IF i were to get the cookie value of the PHP session from a user that is logged in, and visit you website. I could just add a cookie with the same value and the server would recognize me as that user for as long as the session is valid. You need to take extra steps server side if you want to avoid this. Like for example store sessions in a database instead, and have them verified against that visitors IP address or such

Comment: @OleHaugset - IP is no good. If a person is given out there session ID then there is very little you can do. They might as well be given out there password.

Comment: @EdHeal that was just a suggestion to one way of approaching it. The posibilites of how to solve this problem are endless. My answer was, instead of storing sessions the regular way and only verifying that a session is set, is to store a session parameter in a database, with the visitors IP assigned to that current session. Then in the PHP authentication script, verify that the visitor have a session set, check if session is active in database, and that the visitors IP matches the one stored with session in the database. Thus, only stealing the session value will nott suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is only excecuted client side, (exception is nodejs). So no harm can be done to the server.

Comment: Depends on the security of the server.

Comment: If you can kill your server with javascript your server deserves to be brought down because it was designed for that purpose.

Comment: @MartijndeLangh: All servers can be killed with javascript by simply making a ton of requests. You just need enough users to run enough ajax requests. It doesn't even need to be malicious. You could be at fault yourself for not anticipating that **that** many people could possibly be interested in your app and design your app to make 10 requests per second (you know, just to keep it "interactive"). I remember the first time I deployed a facebook app -- we weren't ready for it.

Comment: @slebetman Then the server would not be killed by javascript, there are many ways to create a denial of service attack. Saying that javascript can kill a server by sending tonns of request is the same as saying that Google Chrome can kill a server if many users hit F5 continouesly. Making 10 requests a second to make something interactive is by definition bad design

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs in the users browser.We dont have any control over it.

The thing you can do is to `obfuscate or hash variable names and/or values`.

See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939773/how-to-prevent-javascript-injection-attacks)

Comment: This does not really work. Just take an exact copy to hijack the session

Comment: @EdHeal as i told js runs under users browser and we have no control over it..what we can do is by using server side scripts